# How do I implement a cometd client that can handle NTLM authentication

Tags: java, apache, jetty, apache-httpclient-4.x, cometd

I'm currently creating a JavaFX client as an alternative to a web-based client. We use cometd for push notifications to the browser, and if I can get away with it, I want to minimize the number of changes to the server, so I'm trying to implement a cometd client in Java.

The problem lies in the fact that we use spring authentication on the server via NTLM. The Jetty HttpClient doesn't appear to support this, and cometd doesn't appear to support Apache's httpclient which does support NTLM.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Have you considered using async version of Apache HttpClient in streaming mode? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchangeStreaming.java

Comment: Jetty doesn't seem to support alternative httpclients, so no. For now I have disabled authentication for cometd messaging, and will attempt to solve the problem at a later date. Thanks for commenting though.